# Does any scriptures discuss any other mantras besides the Shiva Panchakshara mantra that do not require diksha or initiation?

Tags: mantras, mantra-diksha

Skanda Puran - Verses 3.3.1.20 and Verse 3.3.1.21 - [Brāhma-khaṇḍa->Brahmottar-khad->Chapter 1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423663.html) clearly states the glory of the Shiva Panchakshar mantr as follows -

> तस्मात्सर्वप्रदो मंत्रः सोऽयं पञ्चाक्षरः स्मृतः । स्त्रीभिः शूद्रैश्च संकीर्णैर्धार्यते मुक्तिकांक्षिभिः ॥ २० ॥
>
> नास्य दीक्षा न होमश्च न संस्कारो न तर्पणम् । न कालो नोपदेशश्च सदा शुचिरयं मनुः ॥ २१ ॥
>
> 20. Hence this **five-lettered Mantra is declared as the bestower of everything. It may be practised (muttered) even by women, Śūdras and men of mixed caste and nativity desirous of salvation.**
> 21. **There is neither special initiation in regard to this Mantra nor Homa; neither consecration nor water-libation (or other means of propitiation); neither a special occasion nor special process of instruction. This Mantra is ever pure**

ALSO

Shiv Puran ([Vayaviya Samhita-uttarbhag-chapter 14](https://archive.org/details/SzWh_shiv-mahapuran-of-veda-vyas-chapter-2-second-half-with-hindi-vyakhya-illustration-gita-press/page/n951/mode/2up?view=theater)) also tallies

> पञ्चाक्षरात्परं नास्ति परित्राणं कलौ युगे ॥ ६२
> गच्छतस्तिष्ठतो वापि स्वेच्छया कर्म कुर्वतः ॥ अशुचेर्वा शुचेर्वापि मन्त्रो ऽयन्न च निष्फलः ॥ ६३
> अनाचारवतां पुंसामविशुद्धषडध्वनाम् ॥ अनादिष्टो ऽपि गुरुणा मन्त्रो ऽयं न च निष्फलः ॥ ६४
> अन्त्यजस्यापि मूर्खस्य मूढस्य पतितस्य च ॥ निर्मर्यादस्य नीचस्य मंत्रो ऽयं न च निष्फलः ॥ ६५
>
> 62. In the age of Kali there is no greater protective factor than the five-syllabled Mantra to a fallen or a low-born person devoid of good conduct.
> 63. This mantra is not ineffective when repeated by a person whether walking or standing or doing any other work or whether he is pure or impure.
> 64. **This mantra is not ineffective even if it is not properly imparted by the preceptor.** It is not ineffective even in the case of persons not caring for good conduct and who have not purified the six paths.
> 65. This mantra is not ineffective in the case of a base-born, a fool, a deluded person, a fallen man and a lowly one transgressing the bounds of decency.

**My question is that does any other scripture explicitly recognizes similar freedom (in terms of not requiring initiation from guru or one being free to devotedly chant that mantr in any place, any time, be it any condition) for any other mantra ?**

NOTE that, I am specifically asking for mantras only, NOT for any "naam-jaap" (like - Radhe-Shyam, Sita-Raam, Uma-Maheshvar, etc,..